# Quicker Way to Compute Modulus?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Are there any tricks associated with finding a large value $mod$ another value? I'm working on problems that involve computing the Legendre symbol value and need to take the modulus of another prime frequently. Is there a quick way of doing this. For example, is the only way to compute 127 $mod$ 7 is by going through manually and seeing how many times 7 goes into 127 etc.

Comment: It can be useful to note that $ab \mod n = (a \mod n) \times (b \mod n) \mod n$

Comment: 127 is prime though, so that won't work in this case, but for composite numbers I can see that being useful

Comment: What is 70 mod 7, we have 57 mod 7 left over, what is 49 mod 7, we have 8 left over, what is 8 mod 7 = 1. Clear? You can also do things like using the binary expansion and others. For example 2^3 = 1 mod 7 and how many 2^3 are there in 127. Just different approaches to consider.

Comment: That makes sense and is an interesting approach

Comment: Are you looking for a quick way to do this by hand, or computationally?

Comment: By hand, no computers need be involved

Comment: Well, for a small modulus like $7$, long division is actually very quick.

Comment: True, but I was just trying to see if there was a quick method out there that I just didn't know about

Comment: Long division for just finding the remainder is especially quick, since you don't actually need to bother about keeping track of the quotient.

Comment: @Amzoti:  Why at the point of 57 mod 7 do you not just immediately say 'what is 56 mod 7, we have 1 left over'?  What you are doing is really just (slightly inefficient) long division.

Comment: @TaraB: I can do it in my head in one step with such small numbers. I was trying to provide hom with some mental examples for him to play with and explore. I would use something like repeated squaring, Fermat's Little theorem and related approaches. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$127 = 5^3 + 2$

Therefore,

$$
\begin{align}
127 \ \mod 7 &\equiv (5^3 \ \mod 7 + 2 ) \ \mod 7\\
&\equiv (\left( (25 \ \mod 7) * 5 \ \mod 7\right) \ \mod 7 + 2) \ \mod 7 \\
&\equiv ((20 \ \mod 7) + 2 ) \ \mod 7 \\
&\equiv 8 \ \mod 7 \\
&= 1
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I was looking for something a little more general, but I can see the techniques used which is good.

Comment: @Benzne_O The modulus operation is inapt. You can not generalise it easily.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I think that $127$ is in the mental arithmetic range. $14159265358979323846$ OTOH...

Depending on the modulus there are several tricks. I'm sure you can handle modulo $2,3$ or $5$. For the next three primes the following series of exercise gives you a shortcut.

1. Check that $1001=7\cdot11\cdot13$
2. If $p$ is any of $7,11,13$, then
   $$1000b+a\equiv-b+a\pmod{p}$$ for all integers $a,b$.
3. If $p$ is any of $7,11,13$, then
   $$1000000c+1000b+a\equiv c-b+a\pmod{p}$$ for all integers $a,b,c$.
4. Continue this for larger integers...

So for example $324598177\equiv 324-598+177=501-598=-97\equiv1\pmod7$.
This will allow you to reduce a large number modulo $7,11$ or $13$ to a 3-digit integer. Of course, nothing prevents you from using whatever tricks you can find 
to effeciently deal with those 3-digit numbers.

For example (concentrate on $p=7$ here):

1. $10\equiv 3\pmod7$.
2. $100=10^2\equiv3^2=9\equiv2\pmod7$.
3. So $100a+10b+c\equiv 2a+3b+c\pmod7$.

As an example
$$
127=100\cdot1+10\cdot2+7\equiv 2\cdot1+3\cdot2+7\equiv2+6\equiv1\pmod7.
$$